# How to send value of ng-repeat to other class in HTML using Agrular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to send value to java-script class  as per following code snippets,

```
 <div  class="GaugeMeter" 
        data-percent="50"
        data-append=" psi"
        data-size="130" 
        data-theme="#33ccff"
        data-back="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
        data-animate_gauge_colors="1"
        data-animate_text_colors="1"
        data-width="15"
        data-label="56 °" 
        data-style="Arch" 
        data-label_color="#FFF"> 
     </div>
```

I am using Angularjs and HTML for send and display value

```
<p ng-repeat="v in infoDetails">
    <div  class="GaugeMeter" 
        data-percent="{{v.pressure}}"
        data-append=" psi"
        data-size="130" 
        data-theme="#33ccff"
        data-back="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
        data-animate_gauge_colors="1"
        data-animate_text_colors="1"
        data-width="15"
        data-label="56 °" 
        data-style="Arch" 
        data-label_color="#FFF"> 
    </div> 
</p>
```

But i am not able to send value of pressure in other div. So How I can achieve this.

Thank you in Advance !!

Comment: What do you mean by `send parameter of pressure in other div` ? In which `div` do you want to send it ? or do you want to use something similar to `ng-attr-id` ??

Comment: I want to send Value to **data-percent** from ng_repeat array.. as per above code snippets

Comment: Check my answer.In case you need more help, update your question with the 'js' logic which you want to achieve in your code. I can try to help you with how to move it to `directive`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve will be buggy unless you do it angularJS way.

Reason being, you are trying to pass a value to some attribute which is not in sync with `digest` cycle of AngularJS. What happens is that the `html` is rendered but the `{{ exression}}` is yet to be evaluated and updated. It's not aware of angular `digest` cycle

I would recommend you to use `directives` and handle the scenario. Pass these values to directives and accordingly write the `javascript` code

Comment: @NitinKarande: Cool. if it works for you, mark it as an answer